# Spring Security and Angularjs Login

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security

The example in this link: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/, uses an end point named user. Then with $http.get in angular the app try to reach that end point. If it reached it means that the user is authenticated.

In my demo app I am using $http in a post to my login end point. Doing so it will authenticate the user as well. Now my question: Which one should I use? Is it any difference between then besides the http verb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `/user` endpoint in the example is to verify authentication, even with that you have to have a separate endpoint, say `/login POST` for the actual authentication itself.

On a side note, as per my understanding, as per the guide we check `/user` each time we do a backend call which imho is not a very good design. If you are planing to implement this approach in your app you can consider any other alternatives..

Comment: I am using a post so spring security handle the login. Is that a better approach?